# Neither QtCreator, nor qtchooser can see the installed qt6

Tags: qt, configuration, frameworks, qt-creator

I've just installed Debian 12, and what I suppose is the whole of Qt6 -- tools and library

But unfortunately the Qt6 library is not seen.

When I type `qtchooser -l`, it lists:

```
4
5
default
qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt4
qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu
qt5
```

When I start `qtcreator`, it presents `Qt 5.15.8 in PATH (qt5)`, but not Qt6

And yet qtcreator uses qt6, as the result of `qtcreator -version` is

```
Qt Creator 9.0.2 based on Qt 6.4.2
```

How can I make the Qt6 library visible to the Qt tools ?

Comment: The Qt version that Qt Creator is based on is just the version it was built with, not the one you could use. How did you install Qt6 and where was it installed? And do these help: [Setting up new Qt versions](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake.html#setting-up-new-qt-versions), [Why doesn't Qt Creator recognize a Qt installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207726/why-doesnt-qt-creator-recognize-a-qt-installation-directory).

Comment: Can you locate the Qt6 qmake?